# How to create a new column based on conditional statement in Teradata query report?

Tags: teradata

My table contains a column named "notes". I need to create a column `Temper` in my report.  If I spot a word "angry" in the notes, then my new variable `Temper` should be `3`. If I spot a word "indifferent" then `Temper=2`, otherwise `Temper` should equal to `0`.

The initial table:

```
Id  State  Gender  Notes
1    IL     M      Kind of angry, but...
2    MI     F      Maybe indifferent also...
3    IL     F      Was cool but not necces...
```

The result should be like this:

```
    Id      Temper
    1          3
    2          2
    3          0
```

I am not sure how to do this in Teradata environment:

```
select Id, (notes like '%angry%')=3 else // ?????
from customers
where
case
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select id, 
       case 
         when notes like '%angry%' then 3
         when notes like '%indifferent%' then 2 
         else 0
       end as temper
from customers;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Could you direct me to a good tutorial for Teradata? I have been trying to use the `Oracle` statements like `select * from user_constraints` but nothing worked...

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA: `user_constraints` is an Oracle system catalog. I don't see the relevance of that for this query. I would assume that those catalog tables are documented in the Teradata manual.

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA: Most of the Oracle SQL syntax is quite similar to Teradata/Standard SQL. CASE is Oracle syntax for at least 10 years (replacing DECODE).